# Store product details from URL

Tags: javascript, url, web-scraping

Is there a method or is it even possible to get a products details by using a URL.  Let's say I paste a URL of a product from a store like Walmart Or bestbuy, would it be possible to write something to retrieve the product info (price, name, info, etc..) does this exist? Or would this have to be something site specific that I can write for each specific store?

Comment: Yes, but it's very hard and usually forbidden by the target site's T&C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not using JavaScript due to [same-origin-policy](/questions/tagged/same-origin-policy). You must send that URL to the server, read that external page on the server side and return results back to the server.

On the server side (in whichever language you are using) download the web page, parse it (using [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)/[xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) if you can) and extract relevant information.

As already noted watch out, some websites forbid such access (called web-scraping), other might actively try to prevent that, e.g. by discovering *fake* clients.

Comment: So basically, in doing so this is always going to be considerd "web-scraping" which many sites do not allow, however, if sites have apis for their products, that would be the legal route?

Comment: @user570098: of course. However often APIs require authentication and have some rate limiting implemented. But as long as you follow T&C, you should be fine

Answer (score 2):

One solution I see is to parse the HTML code of the page the URL redirects to using for example [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), but I'm not sure the e-commerce website in question will like that very much `:)` Maybe you could ask them if they have implemented an API to access their products data?

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is website scraping and yes, it's possible and there are loads of tools out there to help you with it.  Some websites aren't happy with you doing it though.

You could do it in C# using the HttpWebRequest class to request data from a url and then parse it with something like XmlReader or the http://html-agility-pack.net/